Caulking outdoor gas fireplace
I would like to know what type of caulking i would use to seal the gap between the firebox & the tile face of the fireplace. The Grout has already failed. Unit is Napoleon Galaxy 55000 BTU/Vent less


Please put all information in your question post, not down here. Take the [tour].

Perhaps some kind of fire block sealant...
